# Xcode. Scheme is missing on one branch

Tags: xcode, git, xcode6, branch, xcode-scheme

I've run into one thing I've never seen before. Throughout this week I've worked with several branches in my project and they all have been committed and pushed to the origin and now, when I'm home I decided to work for a while. But when I switch to one of those branches the scheme to run the app is missing. Only CocoaPods schemes available. This is how it looks:

[image]

It's only on one particular branch. When I switch to another branch then it's ok, this scheme is present and I can run the app successfully. What's that? How to fix it?